# Extending the return dictionairy of a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have this function which I like to extend. The function returns a dictionary.

```
def _prepare_order_line_procurement(self, cr, uid, order, line):
    return {
        'name': line.name,
        'origin': order.name,
        'date_planned': date_planned,
    }
```

How would I add the key value pair `'incoterm': order.incoterm` to the return dict. The function would become this

```
def _prepare_order_line_procurement(self, cr, uid, order, line):
    return {
        'name': line.name,
        'origin': order.name,
        'date_planned': date_planned,
        'incoterm': order.incoterm,
    }
```

For dictionaries you have the function `update()` but I do not know how to apply this for extending a function. `incoterm` is here an example, for other functionality it can be other key value pairs that need to be added. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean you want to wrap the function in a decorator? Presumably you cannot edit the function?

Comment: Either edit the function, or just update the dictionary that the function returns after calling. However, it is not clear what you want here.

Comment: An analog to underscore's `extend()` in python is `dict(original, **extension)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish — but perhaps it's something like this, which uses what is called a [*function or method decorator*](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-318-decorators-for-functions-and-methods) which in this case would modify the dictionary returned by the function.

```
def add_incoterm(f):
    def decorated(self, cr, uid, order, line):
        result = f(self, cr, uid, order, line)  # call original function
        result.update(incoterm=order.incoterm)  # add key value pair to result
        return result  # return updated result
    return decorated

@add_incoterm
def _prepare_order_line_procurement(self, cr, uid, order, line):
    return {
        'name': line.name,
        'origin': order.name,
        'date_planned': date_planned,
    }
```

However, if you have the source code for the method, it would make more sense (and be more efficient) to just to modify the code in it include the additional data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going to try this. The code is from openerp. You can edit the source code but I am developing a module which you hook into the framework. You are supposed to place the module in a separate add-on folder.

Comment: MaartenM: For patching a framework you might want to use a [class decorator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) which is similar concept and has been backported into Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you're asking for simple solution here. Decorators are made for not touching your function and extending it's behaviour, but it may be complicated.

```
def _prepare_order_line_procurement(self, cr, uid, order, line, **kwargs):
    reply = {
        'name': line.name,
        'origin': order.name,
        # Where did you get this thing? Maybe it should be provided in kwargs?
        'date_planned': date_planned, 
    }
    reply.update(**kwargs)
    return reply
```

See how you should use it in such case, data is sampled to make function runnable.

```
# Some tests
_prepare_order_line_procurement(None, cr, uid, order, line) == \
      {'origin': 3, 'name': 4, 'date_planned': None}
_prepare_order_line_procurement(None, cr, uid, order, line, something='anything') == \
      {'origin': 3, 'something': 'anything', 'name': 4, 'date_planned': None}
_prepare_order_line_procurement(None, cr, uid, order, line, **{'something': 'anything', 'blah': 'blah'}) == \
    {'origin': 3, 'blah': 'blah', 'something': 'anything', 'name': 4, 'date_planned': None}
```